# Why do I get two extra values in data frame column while I've already filtered it?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to select the rows which have the values of their label column equal to 'unreg', so I do:

```
df =df[df$label == 'unreg',]
```

So I assume when I get the values of this column, it should be only 'ureg', but:

```
table(df$label)
```

shows

```
20170131 20170224    unreg 
   0        0        0   1000
```

Why it is showing these two extra values (20170131 and 20170224) with a frequency of 0?

Comment: It happens when label column is a factor already defined with levels/labels c("20170131", "20170224", "unreg"). Try class(df$label) and see what the results are? If you want to get rid of it, you can redefine factor levels/labels.

Answer (score 0):

Let me write this down as a formal answer: let's try creating a minimal example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
label <- c("20170131", "20170224", "unreg", "ureg")
df <- data_frame(label)
df %<>% 
  mutate(label = 
    factor(label, levels = label) # The vector label, not the column
  )
```

After this, you will see that

```
> class(df$label)
[1] "factor"
> df$labels
[1] 20170131 20170224 unreg    ureg    
Levels: 20170131 20170224 unreg ureg
```

Let's try performing the following as you suggested again:

```
> df =df[df$labels == 'unreg',]
> table(df$labels)
20170131 20170224    unreg     ureg 
       0        0        1        0
```

To get rid of the now nonexistent levels of the factor, we can simply

```
df %<>% mutate(labels = factor(labels))
```

Then you see that

```
> table(df$labels)
unreg 
    1
```

You may want to redefine your own levels/labels at this point, of course.
Let me know if this doesn't work out or this wasn't what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to R, when I run df %<>% mutate(labels = factor(labels)), it does not recognize %<>%

Comment: `%<>%` is an operator from the `magrittr` package. A more "standard" way to drop empty levels of a factor would be: `df$label = droplevels(df$label)`. If you want to use the `dplyr` pipe operator (`%>%` note the difference from `%<>%`) you can do: `df = df %>% mutate(label = droplevels(label))`. The two-way pipe `df %<>% mutate(label = droplevels(label))` updates the original object (`df` in this case) without the need for `df = ...` at the beginning to make the assignment explicit.

Comment: I call ```library(tidyverse)``` and ```library(magrittr)``` in the beginning. Yes, like @eipi10 mentioned, there's no need to resort to the ```dplyr``` or ```magrittr``` package. I just prefer them.